# How to use woocommerce array from shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

By looking at this documentation 
https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html it shows a lot of functions like

> WC()->cart->check_cart_items();

which does work

Problem is when I try to print out array like in this case

> $cart_contents

it just shows up as empty object

I did try to use

> WC()->cart->init();

but result is the same.
What could be the problem preventing from activating this object

Comment: What you want to get?

Comment: what code did you use to print it?

Comment: @MahaDev i want to get cart content array which should include item name and price

Comment: @Reigel print_r() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use global woocommerce variable like this:

```
<?php 

    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($items);
    die;
?>
```

Comment: WC() is the same as declaring `global $woocommerce;` and then calling `$woocommerce;`